# Why I have this weird GUI in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: power-management, icons, gui, 21.10

I don't know why, but I have this strange GUI and it doesn't allow me to execute anything like Power Off or even execute the terminal.

All the icons are gone.

It just allows me execute google chrome, internet, but nothing else.

To Power Off my PC, I have to press CTRL+ALT+SUPR and then the normal ubuntu options appears.

Can anyone help me to figure out what's going on, please?

[image: My current Ubuntu GUI image attached]

Comment: How did you get to this situation? Is it MATE desktop environment? How it was installed? Which installation media did you use for installation?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It was installed by an iso image via USB.

Comment: Before I had Windows 7. But I switched to Ubuntu 21.10 with the iso image. The latest version I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "screenshot" looks like some "custom" system with MATE desktop. To make it look better you have to open terminal and run below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

and then reboot and select MATE on login screen, then login to this session.

To reset desktop settings you have to run below command:

```
dconf reset -f /
```

To restart NetworkManager use below command:

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Comment: Sure! No problem!